# How to get information on php telegram bots from JSON on the site

Tags: php, json, bots, telegram

I would like to receive the app on this site. So the boat needs to get the word uzbekistan. but it does not work!

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/uzbekistan");
$json = json_decode ($json);
$res = $json->name;
if(isset($text1)){
  bot('sendmessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
    'text'=>"$res" //there is 'Uzbekistan'
  ]);
}
```

Comment: What is `$text1`?

Comment: input text @text1

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
$json = json_decode ($json);
$res = $json->name;
```

To:

```
$json1 = json_decode($json, true);
$res = $json1[0]['name'];
```

And you will get the name, because your entering the array in index[0] with the first parameter being ['name'].

Comment: It worked. But there is another problem. How do I get 'TopLevelDomain' from here?

Comment: It's easy. You just gotta follow the pattern. In this case if you wanna access the "TopLevelDomain" you do $json1[0]['topLevelDomain'][0] . You have to put the [0], because that's an array and you go to his first position of the index which is [0], and voilá